# Correct way in solving inequalities?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

\begin{align*}
& 2n \log_{10}⁡n \le 0.1n^2 \\
\iff & 20n \log_{10}⁡n \le n^2 \\
\iff & 20 \log_{10}⁡n \le n \\
\iff & \log_{10}⁡(n^{20}) \le n \\
\iff & \log_{10}(n^{20}) \le n = \log_{10}⁡(10^n ) \\
\iff & n^{20} \le 10^n \\
\iff & n=1 \quad \text{or} \quad n \ge 30
\end{align*}
Is this the correct way of solving inequalities?

Comment: How did you obtain $n = 1$ or $n \le 30$? Note that if $n = 1$, we have $n \le 30$.

Comment: For $n \le c$, where $c \approx 1.14$, we have $n^{20} > 10^n$ and for all larger $n$, the opposite inequality is true.

Comment: You final step cannot be correct, because  $n^{20}=o(10^n)$.

Comment: But where does $30$ come from? As a check, I notice $n=10$ gives a false result for every step before the very last, but $10 \leq 30$.

Comment: So pretty much the $n\le 30$ makes no sense?

Comment: Not really. Where did it come from?

Comment: The $30$ is correct. Think about Lambert function.

Comment: I suspect you made a typo and meant "$n = 1$ or $n \geqslant 30$".